# join same table in sequelize and print in excel

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nodes

I want to print parent name in excel

this is my code

```
function getReportT0Print(req, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Product.findAll({
      where: {
        $and: [
          {
            public: true,
            visible: true,
            ancestry: {
              $not: null,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: ormDb.Document,
          required: false,
        },
      ],
      attributes: ["name", "slug", "folder_path"],
    })
      .then(function (data) {
        // console.log("data" + data.length);
        var rows = [];
        rows.push(["Product Name", "Slug", "File Path", "Product Parent Name"]);
        data.map(function (product) {
          rows.push([
            product.name,
            product.slug,
            product.folder_path,
            (here i need to print parent name)
          ]);
        });
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("products_with_tags");
        sheet.addRows(rows);
        resolve(workbook);

        return res.send("successfull");
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

i can print name, slug,folder_path but i don't know how to print parent name in excel file
as parent name is not present but i have given parent_id in place of parent name and want to print parent name

my SQl table look like this
("id" "name" "version" "published" "reviewed" "visible" "public", "parent_id")

Comment: Do you have an association from `Product` to `Product` using `parent_id`?

Comment: yes @Anatoly whenever i add new child product that time i provide parent_id to child product

Comment: I mean Sequelize association like 'Product.belongsTo(Product, ...'

Comment: no i dont know how to do that @Anatoly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register an association between two `Product` models like this:

```js
Product.belongsTo(Product, { foreignKey: 'parent_id', as: 'parent' });
```

You can place it in some module outside model's module file where you create Sequelize instance, for example.

To use this association you need to use the same `include` option as you did with `Document`:

```js
Product.findAll({
      where: {
        $and: [
          {
            public: true,
            visible: true,
            ancestry: {
              $not: null,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Product,
          as: 'parent',
          required: false, // or true if parent_id is required field 
          // or you wish to get all products with parents
          attributes: ["name", "slug", "folder_path"],
        },
        {
          model: ormDb.Document,
          required: false,
        },
      ],
      attributes: ["name", "slug", "folder_path"],
    })
```